# MVC 4 display error messages from the BAL/BLL layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an user register systems using ASP.Net MVC 4 and ADO.net (not EF).

I have this method in my BAL/BLL layer:

```
    public static void InsertMemberUsername(RegisterRequest register, Guid id_fk)
    {
        if (Exist(register.UserName.Username))
        {
            // display error message to pick some other username
        }

        MEMBER_USERNAME entityToCreate = CreateMemberUsername(register, id_fk);
        MEMBER_USERNAME_DAL.SQLAtlInsert(entityToCreate, "Server=ConnSting Here;");
    }
```

In my controller I have this:

```
    [CaptchaMvc.Attributes.CaptchaVerify("Captcha is not valid")]
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterRequest model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Membership_BAL.Register(model);
            // TODO: Redirect user to profile page
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        TempData["Message"] = "Error: captcha is not valid.";
        return View();
    }
```

The InsertMemberName method is called inside of the Register method.

What would be the best to display an error message if the username is already be used?

Comment: A better way to do this would be to use MVC Remote validation to validate the username as part of the validation process.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is obviously various ways to achieve this.

Modify your function from

```
public static void InsertMemberUsername(RegisterRequest register, Guid id_fk)
{
    if (Exist(register.UserName.Username))
    {
        // display error message to pick some other username
    }

    MEMBER_USERNAME entityToCreate = CreateMemberUsername(register, id_fk);
    MEMBER_USERNAME_DAL.SQLAtlInsert(entityToCreate, "Server=ConnSting Here;");
}
```

to

```
public static bool InsertMemberUsername(RegisterRequest register, Guid id_fk)
{
    if (Exist(register.UserName.Username))
    {
        return false;
    }

    MEMBER_USERNAME entityToCreate = CreateMemberUsername(register, id_fk);
    MEMBER_USERNAME_DAL.SQLAtlInsert(entityToCreate, "Server=ConnSting Here;");

    return true;
}
```

I prefer to have a parameter within my model representing an error message and not to use TempData. Something like

```
public class SomeModel
{
     public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
     // Your other model parameters go here.
}
```

Then you can set the parameter in your model like this

```
var someModel = new SomeModel();

if(!InsertMemberUsername( // You parameters))
{
    someModel.ErrorMessage = "Error: captcha is not valid.";
}
```

And pass this model to your view like this

```
return View(someModel);
```

Within your view you can now display the contents of this parameter, for example

```
<div>
    @if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.ErrorMessage))
    {
        @Model.ErrorMessage
    }
</div>
```